# struct forward declaration in C

Tags: c

I want to hide a specified struct in my c module, so struct declaration is in the *.c file and the header contains a typedef. Something like this:

```
/* member.h */
typedef struct MEMBER_T *member_t;

/* member.c */
#include "member.h"
struct MEMBER_T {
    unsigned int member_id;
    char name;
};
```

and later in the c file I want to do a member table:

```
members = calloc(10, sizeof(member_t));
```

but it's wrong, I know. 
How can I use thie solution? I mean how can I create an object for member_t?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your example, `sizeof(member_t)` is the size of a pointer to structure `MEMBER_T`. Also, what is the actual problem? What is "wrong"?

Comment: Did you add the forward declaration or not?

Comment: Yes, but it calloced 10 * sizeof(member_t) which is 40 byte. And I can't give values in the char* name. I mean it's not working: members[0]->name = "test".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating an array. you still need to allocate each of its elements.

If you want to hide the struct in .c file, than it would also be a good idea to encapsulate its creation. So the user of you struct will not ha to bother whether to user `sizeof(member_t)` or `sizeof(*member_t)` or `sizeof(struct MEMBER_T)`.

define a function `membet_t* create_member_array(int)` in you header in addition to `typedef struct MEMBER_T* member_t`.

implement it in you .c file

```
member_t* create_member_array(int length) {
    member_t* arr = (member_t*) malloc(length * sizeof(member_t));
    if(arr) {
        int i = 0;
        for(; i < length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (member_t) malloc(sizeof(struct MEMBER_T));
            if(arr[i]) {
                arr[i]->member_id = 0;
                arr[i]->name = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

the declaration in you struct `char name;` combined with the statement `members[0]->name = "test"` is not correct. You declar a single char and try to a ssign a string to it, witch itself is not correct. it should be `char* name` and you shold allocate mememory before trying to copy a string to ist using `strcpy()`

```
member[0]->name = malloc((strlen("test") + 1)  * sizeof(char)); // 1 more the terminating '\0' !
strcpy(member[0]->name, "test");
```

alternativ:

```
member[0]->name = strdup("test");
```

This is a lot of memory allocation witch you need to make sure you release / free it. You will have to create another function to free all this memory

```
void free_member_array(member_t* members, int length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(members[i]->name) {
            free(members[i]->name);
        }
        free(members[i]);
    }
    free(members);
}
```

Comment: For the name, why not use `strdup` instead of `malloc` and `strcpy`? Also, your `malloc` is off by one for that.

Comment: strdup is a better alternativ, and OMG ... the terminating '\0' ... xD

Comment: allocate each element for an array?

Comment: an array of pointers to struct MEMBER_T, i guess this was the asker's intention when using calloc

Comment: thanks, obviously members[0]->name = "test" was wrong (I want to finish this, and I hurry). My mistake I didn't understand that the struct is a pointer, and I wanted to use as a type.

Comment: I fixed some bad mistakes in my sample code for the create function, you have to pay attention to the difference. arr[i] needs to point to 8 bytes (sizeof(struct MEMBER_T)) of memory witch is in fact (sizeof(unsigned int) + sizeof(char*)). also added the type cats for the malloc function since it returns void*. Note tha if you use member_t outside of the file where the struct is defined you need to have some getter and setter functions for the members, otherwise you will be unable to access them.

Comment: I cannot explain why it worked with `arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(member_t));` witch allocates only 4 bytes :/ ... i tested it too.

Answer (score 1):

use `sizeof(*member_t)` or `sizeof(struct MEMBER_T)`

Answer (score 1):

If you've hidden the struct definition in a .c file, you can't use sizeof to find its type outside of that module.

The solution is to either expose an function in the module that does the allocation (and perhaps initialisation too), or to provide a function that gives the size.

Or of course, to move the definition back into the header file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate 10 structs of type  member_t you must allocate 10 times the size of the latter, in your code you are only allocating 10 time the size of a pointer:

```
/* member.h */
typedef struct MEMBER_T *member_t; //  here your typedef member_t is on a pointer
```

your second problem is that, if you want to use a char* in your structure, you must allocate what you want to put inside it, if the member name of your struct member_t is a char *, in order to fill this char* with "test" you have to allocate enough space.

```
/* member.h */
typedef struct MEMBER_T member_t;

/*file.c*/
member_t *members;
members = malloc(10 * (sizeof(member_t))); 
// here i allocate 10 structs of type member_t

members[0].name = strdup("test"); 
// here i allocate enough place for "test" by 
// using the strdup function who returns an allocate 
// element.
```

if your printf("%s\n", members[0].name); you will receive "test\n".

Answer (score 0):

Like me and others have said, `sizeof(member_t)` is not the same as `sizeof(struct MEMBER_T)`. That's one of your problems.

The other which you explain in a comment is that you want the `name` member to be a string. The problem here is that you declare the member as a single character. Either declare it as a pointer to a character (`char *name`) or as an array (`char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]`, with `MAX_NAME_LENGTH` something appropriate for you). In the first case I suggest you use `strdup` to copy the strings, but remember to `free` them when done. In the last case, use `strncpy`.